# Get all HTML tags from string using PHP?

Tags: php, html

For example, we have this string:

```
"<span>some text</span><someInVaLIDTAG>some text</someInVaLIDTAG_CLOSED_NOT_PROPERLY><p attr='value'>Text</p>"
```

I nedd to get all tags in array like this:

```
[<span>, </span>, <someInVaLIDTAG>, </someInVaLIDTAG_CLOSED_NOT_PROPERLY>, <p>, </p>]
```

and if there is some tags like  i will just replace all strange tags with valid ones:

```
<someInVaLIDTAG> -> <p>
</someInVaLIDTAG_CLOSED_NOT_PROPERLY> -> </p>
```

Comment: you can use a regular expression, e.g.: `<.*?>` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/15476), but it would probably be better to invest a bit of time in learning [domdocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and/or [domxpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using DOMDocument. See the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). You can search about DOMDocument example in Stack Overflow.